# Giraph is using incorrect version of guava

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, guava, giraph

I am submitting a giraph job to a hadoop 1.2.1 cluster. The job is failing with the following stack trace:

```
2017-04-21 20:37:41,082 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.Closeables.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V
    at org.apache.giraph.zk.ZooKeeperManager.generateZooKeeperConfigFile(ZooKeeperManager.java:591)
    at org.apache.giraph.zk.ZooKeeperManager.onlineZooKeeperServers(ZooKeeperManager.java:617)
    at org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager.startZooKeeperManager(GraphTaskManager.java:357)
    at org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager.setup(GraphTaskManager.java:188)
    at org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphMapper.setup(GraphMapper.java:60)
    at org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphMapper.run(GraphMapper.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

I am using giraph 1.2.0. [Mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.giraph/giraph-core/1.2.0) says giraph is dependent on [guava 18](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Closeables.html). It would make sense that that method doesn't exist as it was removed from guava 16 and is deprecated in [guava 15](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Closeables.html). It does not make sense that giraph is trying to use methods from guava 15. What also doesn't make sense is that the method which throws the exception, `ZooKeeperManager :generateZooKeeperConfigFile` [does not exist](https://github.com/apache/giraph/blob/release-1.2/giraph-core/src/main/java/org/apache/giraph/zk/ZooKeeperManager.java) in giraph 1.2.0.

Here is the dependency section of the jar which is being deployed to the hadoop cluster:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
        <artifactId>titan-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-gremlin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.giraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>giraph-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Running `mvn dependency:tree` shows that it does, in fact, require guava 18. There are no other references to guava.

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.giraph:giraph-core:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
```

Additionally there are no other jars deployed to the hadoop cluster. [Hadoop 1.2.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/1.2.1) does not depend on guava. So, what is going on? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You more than likely have several versions of giraph in your classpath, since you say there's a method conflict. Instead of checking for more Guava, check for more Giraph in your dependency tree.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire There is only one version of giraph in the dependency tree, 1.2.0.

Comment: Well, then it's your runner. Your hadoop 1.2.1 uses a giraph (or zookeeper, most likely zookeeper actually) version that is not compatible with yours. You only checked on `hadoop-core`, not on the whole ['ecosystem'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop) (check the word "ecosystem" in that Wikipedia page to see it includes zookeeper). Try upgrading your runner version of Hadoop to a more recent one. If you can't, downgrade your version of Guava to 15 or earlier as the method you mention was removed in 16 (and not in 15 as you said: it was "only" deprecated at that moment).